# Display:none for data-amount less than 20000

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using a payment system in woocommerce and they have it set to show on products that are over $50. We want to change it to only show on products that are over $200. The html looks likes this.

```
<p id="learn-more" class="affirm-as-low-as" data-amount="6950" data-affirm-color="blue" data-learnmore-show="true" data-page-type="product">
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a little script that only shows this if the data-amount= is greater than 20000.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your javascript files. There is likely a script which finds and toggles the display of elements based on the amount defined in the html data attribute.